# Determinant value of a square matrix whose each entry is the g.c.d. of row and column position

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $n \times n$ matrix with $a_{ij}=\gcd(i,j) , \forall i,j=1,2, \cdots, n$ , then how do we prove $\det A=\prod_{i=1}^n \phi(i)$ ? , where $\phi$ is the Euler's phi function

Answer (score 2):

This is called gcd matrix and Smith determinant, you can find proofs [here](http://waset.org/publications/9996770/two-different-computing-methods-of-the-smith-arithmetic-determinant).

One of the ideas is that, through basic matrix operation,  you can transform the given matrix into a triangular one with $\phi(i)$ in the diagonal line.